# Clean rubbish Autofac configurations?

Tags: configuration, autofac

Just wondering whether there is a good way to find out rubbish configurations in Autofac modules. I mean, while the project is growing bigger and bigger with lots of refactoring done, there could be some classes become unused but they are still registered in the module configurations. Those rubbish classes could get hidden from Reshaper because it is used in the configuration code. I just don't like to go through every line in the configuration code to find whether an interface or class is never used any more and delete them manually.

Would be nice if there is good idea to find out all those rubbish automatically. Please throw in your brilliant thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all your registrations from your container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations property. Then you can attach your code to the Activating lifetime event for all of your registrations so you can get all resolved types. Then you should run/test all the features you have (or resolve all your controllers) so all of your dependencies become resolved. Then you can compare the types that are registered and the types that are resolved. Please be aware of issues running this code such as performance impact, multithreading issues. Here's a simple working example, feel free to improve it:

```
class Program
{
    internal class MyUsedClass : IMyUsedClass {}
    internal interface IMyUsedClass {}
    internal class MyUsedClass2 {}
    internal class MyNotUsedClass {}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // register your modules and types
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<MyUsedClass>().As<IMyUsedClass>();
        builder.RegisterType<MyUsedClass2>();
        builder.RegisterType<MyNotUsedClass>();

        using (var container = builder.Build())
        {
            // get all registered types
            var typesRegistered = new HashSet<Type>();
            foreach (var type in container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations.SelectMany(r => r.Services.Select(s => (s as IServiceWithType).ServiceType)))
            {
                typesRegistered.Add(type);
            }


            // get all resolved types via lifetime events
            // please be aware of performance impact, multithreading, etc
            var typesResolved = new HashSet<Type>();
            foreach (var registration in container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations)
            {
                registration.Activating +=
                    (sender, eventArgs) =>
                    {
                        foreach (var type in eventArgs.Component.Services.Select(s => (s as IServiceWithType).ServiceType))
                        {
                            typesResolved.Add(type);
                        }
                    };
            }

            // application is working
            container.Resolve<IMyUsedClass>();
            container.Resolve<MyUsedClass2>();

            // Types that are registered but were not resolved.
            foreach (var type in typesRegistered.Where(type => !typesResolved.Contains(type)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Registered But Not Resolved: {0}",type);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I think the issue still exists there. At some point of the project, it could have "container.Resolve<MyNotUsedClass>()" in the testing code. And after the usage of MyNotUsedClass has been removed from the production code, the test will still pass.

Comment: @bigbearzhu So running tests to get all used registrations is not for you, try other ways.